# Image resolution for android canvas drawings with zooming

Tags: android, canvas

In my android app I download a image from Url and then scale accroding to the screen size before drawn on canvas as follows. This canvas can be zoomed out till 1.5x.

1) What is the best resolution for these images assuming I am supporting phones and tablets.

```
 InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,
                                    (int) width, (int) height, true);
    //width height are 0.75 of screen width height
    bm.recycle();
    bm = scaledBitmap;
```

2) I then segment the image into 10 pieces using path objects as follows and outline to the image. Outlines are not that sharp in unzoomed and zoomed images. Howto improve the line smoothness and quality.

```
Bitmap piecePicture = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas gfx = new Canvas(piecePicture);
// Canvas gfx = new Canvas(bm);
Paint whitePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
whitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
whitePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
whitePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);

                           //translatedFigure is the path object
gfx.drawPath(translatedFigure, whitePaint);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

gfx.drawBitmap(sourcePicture, 0,
0, paint);

Paint mPaint = new Paint(Color.RED);
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

EmbossMaskFilter mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
//new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
BitmapShader fillBMPshader = new BitmapShader(piecePicture, TileMode.MIRROR, TileMode.CLAMP);
 mPaint.setShader(fillBMPshader);
                mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);

gfx.drawBitmap(piecePicture, 0,0, mPaint );


  //outline pen      
Paint outlinePen = new Paint(Color.BLACK);
outlinePen.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
outlinePen
.setStrokeWidth(1);
outlinePen.setAntiAlias(true);

gfx.drawPath(translatedFigure, outlinePen);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set these flags before drawing the bitmap on the canvas.

paint.setFlags(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);